# AdminLTE template upgrade to the latest Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, adminlte

I am using AdminLTE 2.4 with  Bootstrap v3.4.1. now I need to upgrade my template to Bootstrap 4 or 5. do you know any proper way to do it? is it possible ??

Comment: open all pages and replace the old classes/attributes with the new ones. there is no other way unless you write a code to load pages one by one and replace a with b.